# Creating all modules for DI in the Application class for Android

Tags: android, dagger-2

One of the things I've noticed a lot of developers do is to create a class that inherits from Application and then create a component through dependency injection that includes virtually all the modules that make up their app. This is done in the onCreate method. I find this rather strange. Why would you want to inject every module into an Application class and make it globally available. After all, most of the modules like presenters are bound to a single activity and will never be used for any other activity. So why would you not just create a component in the activity and only include those modules you need, which in the case of an activity would be a presenter class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I agree with the premise: Most applications create a component in Application#onCreate, but I believe that most applications also have separate components that contain per-activity, per-fragment, or per-service bindings, and those components/modules only exist and are only classloaded when you use the specific activity/fragment/service in question.

### Scope and lifecycle

Dagger manages object lifecycle (["scope"](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#singletons-and-scoped-bindings)) through separate components, each of which can have its own set of modules. You annotate your component with one or more scope annotations, and then any bindings you annotate with the same scope (or any classes with that scope annotation and `@Inject`-annotated constructors) will be created exactly once and stored within the component. This is in contrast to Dagger's default behavior, which is to call a `@Provides` method or create a new object instance for each call to a component method or each `@Inject`-annotated field. You are in control of when you create a component instance, so you can control the semantics of your scope: If you were to create a scope annotation called `@PerActivity`, and you create a new component instance for each Activity instance Android creates, then you can be sure that any bindings marked `@PerActivity` will return the same instance across the lifetime of that Activity. Likewise, you might create a `@UserScope` where every user gets a separate component instance. The only standardized scope in JSR-330 is `@Singleton`, which should apply to the entire application.

However, what if you want to mix scopes, such as having a @PerActivity StatusBarPresenter depend on a @Singleton LoginService? Dagger requires you to keep those in two separate components, such that StatusBarPresenter might be defined in an `@PerActivity ActivityComponent` and LoginService might be defined in a `@Singleton ApplicationComponent`. You would need to establish a relationship between this ActivityComponent and ApplicationComponent, which can be done through either *components with dependencies* or *subcomponents*.

#### Components with dependencies

Components with dependencies receive separate code generation, and list their dependencies in the `dependencies` attribute on the `@Component` annotation. At that point, you'll need to specify an instance of that Component on their

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {FooModule.class, BarModule.class})
interface ApplicationComponent { 
  Foo foo();
  // Bar also exists, but is not listed. Let's say Foo uses it internally.
}

@PerActivity @Component(
     modules = {BazModule.class},
     dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class})
interface ActivityComponent {
  Baz baz();
}

ActivityComponent activityComponent =
    DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
        .applicationComponent(yourExistingApplicationComponent)
        .build();
```

ActivityComponent receives its own code generation step, and can compile in parallel with ApplicationComponent; however, ActivityComponent can only access dependency Foo and not Bar. This is because ActivityComponent has ApplicationComponent listed as a dependency, and and ApplicationComponent doesn't list Bar. So Baz, defined on the ActivityComponent, can automatically inject Foo but cannot inject Bar. In fact, if Foo stopped consuming Bar, ApplicationComponent may not even generate the code to create Bar at all.

#### Subcomponents

In contrast, subcomponents are generated as a part of their parent component, such that the parent component acts as a factory.

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {FooModule.class, BarModule.class})
interface ApplicationComponent { 
  Foo foo();
  // This is a subcomponent builder method, which can also return a
  // @Subcomponent.Builder. More modern code uses the "subcomponents" attribute
  // on the @Module annotation.
  ActivityComponent createActivityComponent();
}

@PerActivity @Subcomponent(
     modules = {BazModule.class},
     dependencies = {ApplicationComponent.class})
interface ActivityComponent {
  Baz baz();
}

ActivityComponent activityComponent =
    yourExistingApplicationComponent.createActivityComponent();
// or, from somewhere that ApplicationComponent injects:
@Inject Provider<ActivityComponent> activityComponentProvider;
ActivityComponent activityComponent = activityComponentProvider.get();
```

For subcomponents, the implementation of ActivityComponent is generated at the same time as ApplicationComponent, which also means that ApplicationComponent can evaluate ActivityComponent's needs when it is generating code. Consequently, the code for creating Bar instances will be included in ApplicationComponent if either ApplicationComponent or ActivityComponent consumes it. However, this build step may become slow, because Dagger will need to analyze your entire application's dependency graph.

### Application#onCreate

All of this gets back to Application#onCreate, and to what you're seeing:

- If you have application-scoped singletons, you probably need to get a hold of them from the application (though technically you could also use a static field).
- If you have bindings that are used across your application, even if they're unscoped, you may want to install them in ApplicationComponent just so you don't have to repeat the same binding in each component.
- If you're using subcomponents, then all of your code generation for the whole app is generated in one step at the Application level even though the code is generated as separate classes loaded at separate times. Because the application component acts as a factory, the extra classes are hidden, because your one and only reference to a generated class name may be for the ApplicationComponent instance ("DaggerApplicationComponent").

  - This may result in a smoother developer experience, because you don't need to worry about listing a dependency on the ApplicationComponent interface if you want to access it from an ActivityComponent.
  - This is also nice for Android, because in the subcomponent case Dagger has more information about which bindings are required, so it can sometimes produce more compact code than components-with-dependencies.
  - If you're using `dagger.android` and `@ContributesAndroidInjector`, you are using subcomponents with some syntactic sugar on top. Note that `@ContributesAndroidInjector` can be annotated with scope annotations, and can take a list of `modules` which will be passed along to the subcomponent that it generates. Your call to `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` will create one of those subcomponent instances, classloading the subcomponent and its modules as needed.

So even though you may have very specific components with different lifecycles, it may look like all of your Dagger configuration happens in ApplicationComponent and Application#onCreate and nowhere else.